# UITableView willDisplayCell is being called but not animating initially

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with 4 cells, but the 4th cell is off screen. I have the same animation in all the cells. When I scroll to the 4th cell, willDisplayCell is being called, but the animation doesn't work (even though the UIView.animateWithDuration block is called).

I suspect it's something to do with visibleCells but I can't seem to get it to animate. The cell *does* animate the **second** time willDisplayCell is called though, but obviously this isn't good enough. Any thoughts?

Comment: You will need to post the relevant code for so that we can take a look and figure stuff out.

Comment: But the code doesn't really matter, it's a UIView.animateWithDuration in the willDisplayCell delegate method. I need a hack or a workaround because the problem isn't in my code.

Comment: Well, since its not working the first time, there has to be some error in either the code or the logic of what you are trying to animate inside `animateWithDuration`!
Since there is no code and I have no idea what animation you are trying to achieve, it is sorta impossible to help!

Comment: There is other UI related code in the willDisplayCell method but the animation is the main focus. It all works in the other cells but when this 4th cell becomes visible for the first time, nothing happens despite the method being called automatically. It's a problem with UITableView and I need to force it to animate on initial display.